# Remote connection to CentOS VPS server, can't connect to MySQL host

Tags: c#, mysql, centos, mysql-workbench, remote-access

I am trying to connect to a MySQL database, which is located on a CentOS VPS. I am able to connect to the database using the user, host address and port, but not able to connect using the MySQL Workbench or a c# program I am using.

When I try to access on the server using the following, it is successful, but I can't access it via MySQL Workbench or c# program:

```
mysql -u mysqluser -h IP-ADDRESS-OF-SERVER -p
```

I have added onto the firewall to allow access to port 3306/tcp.

I have tried commenting out the 'binding-address', changing it to the server address, changing it to % or to 0.0.0.0 or to 127.0.0.1

Also I notice when I check the status on the iptables and ip6tables, they are inactive (dead). However, when I start and enable them, this inactivated firewalld (I don't know if this is normal as I am still very new to this).

Comment: Depending on where your VPS is hosted maybe check that you not missing another firewall. For example on Azure you can configure a OS based firewall (UFW) and one on the Cloud‘s cloud‘s network settings...

Comment: I don't think there are any other firewalls. UFW isn't on the server.